# How to measure smartphone audio quality?

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I'm regularly testing smartphones for my blog and I'd like to measure their audio quality (file playback but also call quality).

I thought of connecting the jack port from the smartphone to the line-in input of my soundcard and play some sounds to measure the quality through a software.

I'd like to measure sound quality based on THD, SNR, Crosstalk, ...

Is there a software I could use to do this? Would you recommend another method to achieve the same?

Thanks

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

I found found something that might do the trick. It's a program called RightMark Audio Analyzer, it can use a test signal on external devices to be re-analyzed through line-in.